# How to add a specific style to every fifth div element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add a border to **every** fifth element. The current code I have only select the first 5th element, not every one... what am I doing wrong?

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

        $("#categories .cat:nth-child(5)").css({border: '1px solid red', color: '#ff0000'});

});
```

html:

```
<div id="categories">
    <div class="cat">   cat1    </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat2    </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat3    </div>
    <div class="cat"> cat4 </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat5    </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat6    </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat7    </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat8    </div>
    <div class="cat"> cat9 </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat10   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#categories .cat:nth-child(5n)")
```

Notice the `5n`.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that CSS3 selectors also allow you to do this without using javascript at all:

```
#categories:nth-child(5n) {
    color: #ff0000;
    border: 1px solid red; }
```

*Note: [This does not work in IE8 or earlier.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)*

I wouldn't recommend using this on it's own, but rather in addition to a javascript solution (to ensure cross-browser compatibility). I just think that it might make sense for you to have both so browsers that are CSS3 compatible don't experience any sort of flicker when the Javascript is applied.

Answer (score 1):

didn't test it, but you could try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var counter = 1;
    $("#categories").children().each(function(){ 
        if(counter%5==0)
            $(this).css({border: '1px solid red', color: '#ff0000'});
        counter++;
    });
});
```